# Changing the Text label when a button click initiates a process to convert xml to csv file?

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, jbutton, jlabel

I have a process to convert XML to CSV file. My converter code is working fine. However, I have created a UI window to get the input file and output file paths with a Convert Button to trigger conversion.
Now I want to add a Progress indicator when the conversion is taking place. I have come up with the simple solution to show a label on pane and change its Text when the conversion task is in progress.
But the label text is not changing. Here is the code. Appreciate your help.

`import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InputGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
JTextField xmlInputPath = new JTextField("C:\\InputFile.xml", 30);
JTextField csvOutputPath = new JTextField("C:\\OutputFile.csv", 30);
JTextField parentNode = new JTextField(20);
JButton convertButton = new JButton("Convert");
JLabel progressLabel = new JLabel("");

public InputGUI() {
    super("XML to CSV Converter");
    setBounds(400, 300, 500, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JLabel xmlInputLabel = new JLabel("XML Input File Path: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    JLabel csvInputLabel = new JLabel("CSV Output File Path: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    JLabel parentNodeName = new JLabel("Parent Node Tag: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    parentNodeName.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    pane.add(xmlInputLabel);
    pane.add(xmlInputPath);
    pane.add(csvInputLabel);
    pane.add(csvOutputPath);
    pane.add(parentNodeName);
    pane.add(parentNode);
    pane.add(convertButton);
    pane.add(progressLabel);
    convertButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(pane);
    setVisible(true);
}

private static void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    setLookAndFeel();
    new InputGUI();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        progressLabel.setText("Converting...");
        String inputPath = xmlInputPath.getText();
        String outputPath = csvOutputPath.getText();
        String elementTagName = parentNode.getText();
        inputPath = inputPath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        outputPath = outputPath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        XmlToCsvFileUsingSTAX convert = new XmlToCsvFileUsingSTAX();
        convert.xmlToCsvFileConverter(inputPath, outputPath, elementTagName);
        Message msg = new Message();
        progressLabel.setText("");
        msg.successMessage();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Use a Progress Bar. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for more information and working examples. You will need to restructure your code to use a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Swing is single threaded, this means if you run any long running to blocking operations on the Event Dispatching Thread, it will prevent the UI from been updated.  Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details. I would consider using a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), which would allow to execute the primary conversation in the background, but would also allow you to update the UI safely, as Swing isn't thread safe

Comment: Re code formatting. The type using a single 'back-tick' before and after, only works for single line code. For *multi-line* code, use multi-line code formatting.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.